# Internet Explorer authentication of a REST with domain\username

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, rest, webtrends

I have a working javascript/jQuery REST app with the webtrends' exctraction API, with the exception of IE.

I am sending authentication via SSL - https://[domainname]\[username]:[password]@ws.webtrends.com/v3/Reporting/profiles/10609/Keymetrics/?start_period=current_day-1&end_period=current_day&period_type=agg&format=json

When I look inside of Developer Tools (F12) > under the Network tab, Internet Explorer changes the backslash('\') to a forward slash ('/'), which results in the browser looking for a web site with the value of the domainname.

All other browsers do NOT change the backslash.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/jsonp",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.overrideMimeType("application/jsonp; charset=UTF-8");
        },
        headers: {
            "Authorization": mBaseSixtyFourVar
        },
        url: mXferObj.mUrl
    });

    $.ajax({ 
        success: function(mInfo){        
            mRecvObj = mInfo;
            alert(mRecvObj.data[0].measures.NewVisitors+"");
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("xmlHttpRequest.readyState: "+xmlHttpRequest.readyState+", textStatus: "+textStatus+", errorThrown: "+errorThrown+", mXferObj.mUrl: "+mXferObj.mUrl);
        }
    });
```

I have tried the following:

Inserting this into the ajaxsetup

```
data: "{'domain':'domainname','username':'blabla','password':'blabla'}",
```

With PHP, I have tried using curl, but nothing returned except bool(false):

I tried file_get_contents() but I received open stream errors.

I have this working in FireFox, Opera, Safari, Chrome - why is IE always the hold up to perfection?

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

As requested, here is ONE of the curL codes that I have tried:

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump $output;
```

I have tried the options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[username]:[password]')
```

So many different things that I have tried, that was the last

Comment: Can you show the code you used to attempt this with PHP and curl?

Comment: Updated code to reflect the requested curL code

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Given your comment about supplying username and password in an `XMLHTTPRequest`, I did some research and found that jQuery *does* support this functionality. All you should have to do is add the `username` and `password` parameters to your request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/jsonp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType("application/jsonp; charset=UTF-8");
    },
    headers: {
        "Authorization": mBaseSixtyFourVar
    },
    url: mXferObj.mUrl,
    username: "yourUsername",
    password: "yourPassword"
});
```

**Original Answer**

Simply put, Internet Explorer does NOT support this functionality. It was removed in a previous security update released in 2004:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

> By default, versions of Windows Internet Explorer that were released starting with the release of security update 832894 do not support handling user names and passwords in HTTP and HTTP with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or HTTPS URLs. The following URL syntax is not supported in Internet Explorer or in Windows Explorer:
>   http(s)://username:password@server/resource.ext

Alternatives may include making an AJAX request to your own server, and then once on the server side, perform the request in managed code. For example, if your language of choice is C#, you can use an `HttpWebRequest` and provide the proper `NetworkCredentials` information to complete the request.

Comment: Thanks for your input Cory and I would give you the credit for your answer, but I found this on the same kb - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832414 - this is their answer as a work around

Comment: @user881083: Thanks for following up. I did some more research and provided an updated answer based on your feedback.

Comment: Yes, this would work if I did not have to enter my domain\username for the username, because IE is changing the backward slash to a forward slash. I have tried %5C and escaping the backslash, but nothing seem to work. Once again, I thank you for your feedback